# Beginner recursion and list trouble going past second dimension

Tags: python, list, dimension

I am trying to unembed a list recursively, but I am having trouble with an efficient way to do it past the second dimension. This works fine for the first two dimensions, but without going in depth with more if statements, it will not function past that.

```
UBLst = []
#Appends variables after they are retrieved from list of any dimension
def antidimension(List):
     global UBLst    
     if List == []:
          ReturnLst = UBLst
          UBLst = []
          return ReturnLst
     elif not isinstance(List[0], list):
          if List[0] != []:
               UBLst.append(List[0])
               List.remove(List[0])
               return antidimension(List)
     elif isinstance(List[0], list):
          for item in List[0]:
               UBLst.append(item)
          List.remove(List[0])
          return antidimension(List)
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "unembed"? Can you give an example input and the result you'd like to get for it?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to recursively flatten a list:

```
def flatten(myList):
  if isinstance(myList[0], list):
    out = []
    for x in map(flatten, myList):
      out.extend(x)
    return out
  else:
    return myList
```

This technically should be safe for most common scenarios unless you have something like 2k nested lists.